# How to keep internet connection alive until a given time?

Tags: bash, scripts, internet, ping

I want to keep my internet alive until a given time (say for example until midnight). This is so because the connection I have is based on a 3G HSPA+ connection and I want to wait until midnight to get better offpeak rates. However I want to keep the connection active until such time without disconnecting due to inactivity.

The only option I saw was to ping a random website such as www.google.com, periodically (say every 5 mins).

Are there any other methods ? Can you also provide the script/implementation details of the methods suggested by you ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you except no output, simply put `ping www.google.som` into your `cron` with frequency set to 5 minutes.

Open cron file with `crontab -e` (in terminal)

and add new entry

`*/5 17-23 * * * ping -c1 www.google.com`

Where:

*/5 means every minute divisible by 5

17-23 hours

* every day of month

* every month

* every day of week

Save and you are done.

Comment: `ping www.abc.com` would be sending pings in the background without stop. You can do just **one ping** likes this `ping -c1 www.abc.com`